# uninstall corrupted software

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall

my nephew deleted some files of a software(VS studio 2010);now I wanna uninstall it completely but in ''add or remove programs'' I cant do uninstallation properly,an error message comes up indicating ''' A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components'' then It stops me from going further and exits.
I wonder if there is any way I can unistall bad/corrupted softwares.

Answer (score 2):

You could try running the installation program again.

If it recognises that the software is installed it will give you the options to change what's installed, repair the installation or uninstall. If uninstall from this route doesn't work try doing a "repair" first.

If the installer doesn't recognise that the software is installed then reinstall followed by the uninstall.